# Postgres server side prepared statement sp call with out parameter - wrong metadata resolution

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, jdbc

We are using **Postgres 14.3**, **Springboot 2.6.1** and **JDBC driver 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3'**

We have a problem in a call to a SP. It's a legacy call to a Stored Procedure with many input parameters and 6 scalar type out parameters.
This is the call structure of the SP:

```
 try (CallableStatement cStm = connection.prepareCall("{Call PERSIST(?,?,...?)")) {


            cStm.setString(1, (persistOrderer ? "1" : "0"));
            cStm.setString(2, (persistOrdererAditionals ? "1" : "0"));
            cStm.setString(3, "1");
            cStm.setString(4, (persistBeneficiary ? "1" : "0"));

....

            cStm.registerOutParameter(84, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
            cStm.registerOutParameter(85, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
            cStm.registerOutParameter(86, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

            cStm.registerOutParameter(87, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cStm.registerOutParameter(88, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cStm.registerOutParameter(89, java.sql.Types.DATE);


            cStm.execute();
```

When the statement is no server side prepared (prepareThreshold is not reached) the SP call works perfectly.
On the other hand, if we reach the prepareThreshold, we have this exception invoking the SP:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't change resolved type for param: 84 from 2278 to 1700
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setResolvedType(SimpleParameterList.java:348)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2151)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:83)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    ....
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Debugging we saw that out parameters when the server side statement is enabled are treated as JavaObject in the metadata, and are numerics in the call and the SP code. When the exception comes, another connection is created and we have a few successful calls until we reach the threshold again.

Turning off server side statements with **prepareThreshold=0** fixes the error but it is very inefficient in comparison. And this disables the server side statement for every statement in the app (we have hundreds per transaction), in the end it's not an option for us.

- Why does the server side statement change the parameters metadata when it is activated?
- It's a problem with scalars types only (number, varchar)?
- There is a chance to disable the server side statement for this sp call only?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround, it’s based on using [CallableStatement#setNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setNull(java.lang.String,%20int)) in every out parameter to correct metadata that will be used in server side prepared statements.
Here the correction using the previous example:

```
          cStm.setNull(84, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
          cStm.setNull(85, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
          cStm.setNull(86, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
          cStm.setNull(87, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
          cStm.setNull(88, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
          cStm.setNull(89, java.sql.Types.DATE);

          cStm.registerOutParameter(84, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
          cStm.registerOutParameter(85, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
          cStm.registerOutParameter(86, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

          cStm.registerOutParameter(87, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
          cStm.registerOutParameter(88, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
          cStm.registerOutParameter(89, java.sql.Types.DATE);
```

There is an example in the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html) using **setNull**

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to set null for JPA Stored Procedure also?